# implementing interfaces during VB to VB.NET class migration

Tags: vb.net, class, vb6, arcobjects

I'm migrating the [CenterSnap.cls](http://edn.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=codeExch.sampleDetail&pg=/arcobjects/9.1/Samples/Editing/Snap_Agents/Snap_to_Center_of_Polygons/Visual_Basic/clsCenterSnap.htm) from its vb version to vb.NET and I'm confused about the following 2 errors after I import the vb6 project to VS 2008.

### Err 1

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem

<System.Runtime.InteropServices.ProgId("StackMap.CenterSnap")> 
Public Class CenterSnap
    Implements ESRI.ArcGIS.Editor.ISnapAgent
    Implements ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.IPersistVariant ' <<<<ERROR 1
```

> Error   1 Class 'CenterSnap' must implement 'ReadOnly Property ID As UID' for interface 'ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.IPersistVariant'. Implementing property must have matching 'ReadOnly' or 'WriteOnly' specifiers.    C:\Projects\VB_ActiveX_dll\StackMap\StackMap\CenterSnap.vb  9   16  StackMap

### Err 2

```
Private ReadOnly Property IPersistVariant_ID() As ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.IUID _
Implements ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.IPersistVariant.ID '<<<< ERROR 2
```

> Error 2    'IPersistVariant_ID' cannot implement 'ID' because there is no matching property on interface 'ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.IPersistVariant'. C:\Projects\VB_ActiveX_dll\StackMap\StackMap\CenterSnap.vb  16  94  StackMap

```
        Get
            Dim pID As New ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UID
            pID.Value = "CenterSnap.clsCenterSnap"
            IPersistVariant_ID = pID

        End Get
```

Why is the `Implements ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.IPersistVariant` not implementing?  I have the ESRI.esriSystem referenced in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of the code, the error says it is expecting an UID property, but your IPersistVeriant_ID property is returning an IUID.

I'm not familiar with what an ESRI.ArcGIS thing is, but it looks like UID and IUID are not the same thing.